# Changing Button Text to a number

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am trying a small project in swift.
I have two labels where i get random numbers each time i click a button. 
My question is how can I change the title of the button, to the addition of my two random numbers.
Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var number1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var number2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var result: UILabel!

var randomNumber1:Int = 0
var randomNumber2:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func generate(sender: AnyObject) {

    randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number1.text = "\(randomNumber1)"

    randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number2.text = "\(randomNumber2)"

    result.text = "\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))"  
}
```

Comment: You want to change the button or the result label? Because right now you're altering the result label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func generate(sender: UIButton) {

    randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number1.text = "\(randomNumber1)"

    randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number2.text = "\(randomNumber2)"

    result.text = "\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))"  

    sender.setTitle("\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

**You were missing this line**

```
    sender.setTitle("\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setTitle("\(number)", forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you're changing the text of the `result` label, not the button. To change the `UIButton` `sender`'s title, change your code to the following:

```
@IBAction func buttonPress(sender: UIButton) {

    let randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number1.text = "\(randomNumber1)"

    let randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number2.text = "\(randomNumber2)"

    sender.setTitle("\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, instead of `anyobject` use `UIButton`

```
@IBAction func generate(sender: UIButton) {

    randomNumber1 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number1.text = "\(randomNumber1)"

    randomNumber2 = Int(arc4random())%11
    number2.text = "\(randomNumber2)"

    result.text = "\((randomNumber1) + (randomNumber2))"


    //Just add this line in the code
    sender.setTitle(result.text, forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
}
```